# The Options of Validation list

Tags: vba, excel

In a validation list, can I add an option to facilitate recharging, for example if I put "S" it shows me the elements that start with "S"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround to do this without using VBA and explained [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/autocomplete-validation.htm)

You need to enter the values above your validation cell and hide the rows with the values like this:
[image]

[image].

[image]

It also explains if you would like your list to be on another sheet.

Comment: In your example if you write "B" it does not display anything, because there is 2 that begins with "b"

Comment: It only displays when there is a unique recommendation. If your list items were bara and baza, it would autocomplete when you write bar or baz. If this does not work for you, you can go with the vba solution by inserting combo box instead of using validations. [Here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal11.html) are instructions and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOOuSe_s6pQ) is the video. Good luck.